# Regex to 'dissallow special symbols or spaces', but 'allow numbers and 'uppercase' OR 'lowercase' letters'

Tags: regex

I already use this regex: "^[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}$"

it allows: numbers, uppercase letters, lowercase letters.
it disallows: whitespaces and special characters or symbols.

But I want to modify it to:

**- allow: numbers, and either uppercase letters or lowercase letters.

 - disallow: whitespaces and special characters or symbols.**

Actually i want to use it as regex for Transaction ID.

**Valid examples**:

- TY5TF45TF463CHB7437R *(UPPERCASE+NUMBERS)*
- ecrx3yt4cx345748bnc7547  *(LOWERCASE+NUMBERS)*
- 745367456475647378563745   *(ONLY NUMBERS)*
- hdgfsdgfsdjfgshdgshdgf  *(ONLY LOWERCASE)*
- DHFGSDHGFSHDGFHSGFHSDFH   *(ONLY UPPERCASE)*

**Invalid Examples**:

- sshd434gfhdghHSDGFH324234SDFHSG *(UPPERCASE+LOWERCASE+NUMBER)*
- SDASGDASDhghgshdfsh   *(uppercase+lowercase)*
- dhf hsh-d-f-837_483@^%f#@^#2482  *(special characters)*

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
^(?:[\da-z]+|[\dA-Z]+)$
```

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `[\da-z]+`- Matches digit + alphabets (lowercase)
- `|` - Alternation
- `[\dA-Z]+`- Matches digit + alphabets (Uppercase)
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JAGkM1/2/)

Comment: Could you explain the significance of the `?:` character pair?

Comment: @dgnuff `?:` is used to make groups non-capturing.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do

Answer (score 1):

something like `/^([0-9a-z]+|[0-9A-Z]+)$/m` should do it.

Comment: @Bsquare it is an answer.. check the request and this is a solution

Comment: using `i` flag will result in case insensitivity will which lead to wrong results.

Comment: @CodeManiac - right I forgot to remove it when I copied it from my testing pad. thanks I fixed it